# From where I can get the source code of StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I have a requirement of developing a site same like SE. Is there SE source code available publicly? If so from where I can get or else is there any similar code base some where I can start with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code for Stack Exchange sites is not public.

We do take pains to extract useful parts of our codebase and make them into open source.

Some of these are on [GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/), for example.

There are many [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) out there, however, as [JonW pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216100/from-where-i-can-get-the-source-code-of-stackexchange/216101#comment699181_216100). Most of these are open source.