# When closing a post, send an edit request to an active community member

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, closed-questions

I'm a new lurker in psychology.stackexchange.com and I've noticed that it's getting harder and harder to ask questions, especially because the moderators have kept closing posts that are sometimes very interesting. (Like, pseudoscience questions are being shutdown on a red tape.)

So in order to ease the habit of forming quality questions, I've decided to open up this meta post/feature request/process improvement suggestion.

I think I have a few valid improvement points so that the interesting questions will not be shut down very early on? Two of them are

1. When closing a post, suggest edit.
   When a post is being closed, maybe we can send an "edit request" to an active member?
   I'm sure an active member will be willing to suggest an edit to a question, especially if the question is very interesting
2. Something along the line of #1.

I might be willing to contribute source code for this on my free time or if an urgent need arises. Thoughts or anything?

Comment: Questions aren't closed because they're not interesting; they may be closed because they're hard/impossible to answer objectively.

Comment: Are we assuming in this feature request that the questions by itself are on-topic for the specific site?

Comment: I can also think of third option that is something along you're second and first option.

Comment: While we appreciate your willingness to contribute source code, the codebase isn't open source. To contribute you first need to be hired as a dev. I hear they no longer allow to reach that position by becoming a CM first ...

Answer (score 4):

> When a post is being closed, maybe we can send an "edit request" to an active member?

This is already how it works. Each post with close votes shows up in the close vote queue with the options *leave open*, *close*, *edit*, and *skip*:

[image: interface]

From here, if the post can be salvaged by an edit, an experienced member of the community should edit the post using the edit button (which also votes to leave the post open).

The reopen queue works similarly, but for questions that need reopen votes.

Answer (score 2):

> When closing a post, suggest edit. When a post is being closed, maybe we can send an "edit request" to an active member? I'm sure an active member will be willing to suggest an edit to a question, especially if the question is very interesting.

Questions aren't closed because they're uninteresting - they might be very interesting.  They're closed because they don't belong, they're off-topic etc. - see [What's on-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on that.

Also, why send an edit request to an active member?  That member might already have seen the post and suggested an edit (or voted to close it).

While you may be willing to contribute source code, [the codebase isn't public/open source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216101/798831); you would need to be a developer.